# qt tab widget white border on right and bottom

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtabwidget

When i'm creating tab widget in qt i have white borders. I tried to delete this but when i'm adding stylesheet  `border: none` i also have white borders on top and bottom
For example i added tab widget and selected this style sheet:

```
*{
background: silver;
border:none;
}
```

In example i had set `background: silver`

[image: Example]

Is there a decision of this trouble?

Answer (score 4):

I found decision: use style sheet

```
.QTabWidget::pane{
    border:none
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this forum suggestion:
[Qt.io forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/112044/changing-border-of-qtabwidget)

Put the following inside the stylesheet of **centralwidget** .

```
QTabWidget::pane {<br/> 
    border-top: none;<br/>
    border-left: none;<br/>
    border-right: none;<br/>
    border-bottom: none;<br/>
}
```